# Sinatra using shotgun gem - undefined methoddefault

Tags: ruby, sinatra, shotgun

from Peepcode tutorial 'Meet Sinatra' with shotgun, returns:

`undefined methoddefault for Rack::Handler:Module (NoMethodError)`

(http://hivelogic.com/articles/meet-sinatra/)

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more information to get a good answer? What versions specifically do you have installed of sinatra, shotgun, mongrel, when was that peep-code tutorial written, and does that error get raised when you try starting mongrel?

Comment: The tutorial was from Oct 12, 2009… maybe it's too long ago...unable to see either Sinatra version.  Mongrel 1.1.5, and Shotgun is returning this: 

shotgun version
configuration version not found
$ shotgun -version
Rack 1.0
$ shotgun help
configuration help not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing the gem `rack` corrected the issue for me

Comment: Thanks, I would have never thought to try that, this got me running with Shotgun after a single google search.  :)